# Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android

I'm developing app in that i need show google map using Google Map V2.
I'm getting  following error and automatically app stoped.
**Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.getlocation/com.example.getlocation.Show}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment**

My Minsdk is 12.

Show.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;

public class Show extends Activity {

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show);

         try {
                // Loading map
                initilizeMap();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


    }
    /**
     * function to load map. If map is not created it will create it for you
     * */
    private void initilizeMap() {
        if (googleMap == null) {
            googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // check if map is created successfully or not
            if (googleMap == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initilizeMap();
    }

}
```

Show.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"   
    tools:context="com.example.getlocation.Show" >

  <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.getlocation"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.getlocation.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.getlocation.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="12"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <!-- Required to show current location -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!-- Required OpenGL ES 2.0. for Maps V2 -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Goolge API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyBCMyxIOHjpFyElj67osKbJwsZ8FrEN3Jg" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Show"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_show" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I tried a lot but still getting same error...

Thanks in advance.